# How to implement reset password in Amazon cognito, if we doesn't have email and phone number? We are using loginname for sign-in in cognito account

Tags: amazon-cognito

I want to implement reset password functionality in Amazon Cognito. I am using login name to sign in cognito account. As cognito sends verification code via email or phone and i am not using these fields in user details. How i can implement reset password in case of login name?

Answer (score 0):

You need either an email id or a phone number to reset user password. Both forgot password and admin reset password use the same flow which will throw an invalid parameter error if neither verified phone or email address is registered for the user.